# Android ThreadPool class extend application

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpool

I'm new to multi thread but i have a question :

it's a good pratice to have a class that extend Applications and declare/init there a custom threadpool that would be accesible from any other activity/fragment ?

Or is there a way to declare just in one place a threadpool for all the app ?

Thanks

Comment: Since "all the app" is represented by the class that extends Application, placing there all things common to the application is natural. Including thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a rule of thumb for this things, but like the Android documentation says about this here: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html#ClassStructure, you should use a class with a static instance to retrieve and use the ThreadPool in every Activity you need it.

Comment: Static variables should be avoided whenever possible. Thay are good for constants only. Placing thread pool in Application subclass is way better.

Comment: Not in this particular case, a static ThreadPool is really usefull because it is accessible from everywhere in your app and if activity Context is not needed (and it shouldn't) there is no way to mess yourself up with some hidden memory leaks. Putting a static ThreadPool in custom Application class has no advantages over a static ThreadPool instance, because you shouldn't use a ThreadPool for general purpose task but create specific  ones

Comment: What if i put it in a Service ? I bind every new open activity with this Service and use Thread Pool. It is better ? Is there a best practice for my base question ? Thanks

Comment: The best practice is: if you are in doubt follow the documentation (if exists) and in your case the answer it's in the link i pasted to you. Putting it in a Service and bind/unbind it in each activities will become an hell to handle correctly, avoid it at any cost.